# Check conditions in multiple columns and rows

Tags: r

When we look at the `mtcars` dataset in R:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I want to select the Mazda models with 6 cylinders (`cyl` is 6) and see which of those cars has the most horse power `hp`. Or, alternatively, I want to see which Merc model with 4 cylinders has the highest `hp`.

How can I do that? Do I subset? Or maybe grep?

Comment: It is not clear.  Perhaps `library(dplyr); tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, 'rn') %>% filter(grepl('Mazda|Merc', rn)) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice(which.max(hp))`

Answer (score 0):

You want to check two conditions: The model name of the car and the cylinder numbers, right?

You can subset the data to the rows that satisfy your (double) condition and then see which of the remaining rows has the highest values for the column `hp`

```
bestcar <- function(carname, cyl_nr){
    inds  <- (grepl(carname, rownames(mtcars)) & mtcars$cyl == cyl_nr)
    subdf <- mtcars[inds, ]
    rownames(subdf)[which.max(subdf$hp)]
}

bestcar("Mazda", 6)
# "Mazda RX4"
bestcar("Merc", 4)
# "Merc 230"
```